# Trying to use RemoteFile from a ruby_block

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I've tried to execute a RemoteFile Provider from a ruby_block using what I could cobble together from the internet. Eventually I am settled on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ctgswallow/3409231) giving me the best template to go by. Essentially from what I can read there from a comment 15 days ago this following code should work:

```
ruby_block "parse-json" do
  block do
    f =  Chef::Provider::File::RemoteFile.new("/tmp/googlebackup", run_context)
    f.source "http://google.com"
    f.run_action :create
  end
  action :create
end
```

But all it gives me is this error:

```
[2014-03-28T14:26:08+00:00] ERROR: ruby_block[parse-json] (/tmp/kitchen/cookbooks/jenkins_build_artefact/providers/default.rb line 16) had an error: NoMethodError: No resource or method named `source' for `Chef::Provider::RemoteFile ""'
```

I don't understand what exactly I am doing wrong and I literally can't find any example of anyone doing something like this anywhere on internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using Chef::Provider where you should be using Chef::Resource.

```
ruby_block "parse-json" do
  block do
    f =  Chef::Resource::File::RemoteFile.new("/tmp/googlebackup", run_context)
    f.source "http://google.com"
    f.run_action :create
  end
  action :create
end
```